# How do you call Progress Openedge .p files from C# using the ODBC driver?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there one way or another to have a .p procedure run through a .Net/C# application using the ODBC driver?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The ODBC driver connects to the database via SQL, bypassing the 4gl.

If you need to execute 4gl .p programs from a .net or C# program you would want to call an app server. In really old releases that might be via “open client” or a SOAP service. In newer releases that might be exposed as a REST service.

Comment: While OpenClient has been around since Version 9, I would not call that "very" old. In 12.4 OpenClient has recently been extended with support for .NET core